# Specific string hangs [, [[

Tags: bash, test

While [fuzz testing](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/b9961fdfc239df4c49c9e0816690bfbd27601e24/tests/empty_line_before_eof.sh#L81) I've found that it's possible, by defining

```
var=$'\365\\'
```

, to make both of the following commands (used to remove everything up to the last newline) **hang indefinitely, consuming 100% CPU** in Bash 4.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu):

```
[ -n "${var##*$'\n'}" ]
[[ -n "${var##*$'\n'}" ]]
```

The runaway `bash` process can't be interrupted with `SIGINT` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> or `kill -SIGINT $pid`) or `SIGTERM`, but have to be killed with `SIGKILL`.

I tried to inspect the value using

```
uniname -bcp <<<"$var"
```

but that also hangs. `uniname`, however, is killable with `SIGINT`.

I also checked some other basic commands, but all of them work fine:

```
echo "$var"
printf '%q\n' "$var"
touch -- "$var"
rm -- "$var"
```

What's going on here? Is this reproducible by others? And is this defined behavior?

Comment: I can't reproduce this on version 4.2.45(2)-release. http://sprunge.us/LeaB

Comment: @ChrisDown Interesting! Anyone care to `bisect`?

Comment: No problem with 4.2.42

Comment: Can't reproduce in 4.2.37(1)-release

Comment: Can't reproduce on `GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin12)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a bug in `bash-4.2` up to patch 29 in UTF-8 locales related to globbing with strings containing invalid UTF-8 characters (which `\365\\` is).

You can also reproduce it with:

```
: *$'\365x'
```

That was fixed in [patch 30](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-4.2-patches/bash42-030), see the patch description and [mailing list discussion](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.shells.bash.bugs/16274) for details.